# How to install RVM using 'wget'?

Tags: ruby, curl, rvm, wget

I would like to install RVM to my home folder, and all the installation instructions or scripts use `curl`, but there is no possibility to install `curl` on the system (not enough permissions).

Is it possible to install RVM with `wget`?

Comment: It's not possible to install curl, but it is possible to install multiple versions of ruby? That seems highly unlikely.

Comment: `curl` is an extremely common tool, epecially `libcurl` which is the backbone of many web-based tools. What system are you having trouble finding it on?

Comment: @qqx Why? I am logged in as a user who has no permissions to install new packages on the system, that's why I have to use only tools that are available (wget). But at the same time an isolated install to the home folder is the most common use case of RVM.

Comment: curl doesn't need to be installed as a package, it could also be installed into a directory in your home folder which is included in your `$PATH`.

Comment: @qqx Yes, thank you, I guess this is the easiest way in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible?  Sure, you can clone the repository and make all necessary changes in Wayne's code.  It is *just* a bash script.

But it is listed as a requirement, and use internally, and so might be more than what you would be willing to do for this.  Here is a snippet from his RVM installer file to show you how he is using it in addition to the initial curl command to kick things off, to give you an idea of the things you would need to change.

```
{
  curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/wayneeseguin/rvm/tags |
    sed -n '/"name": / {s/^.*".*": "\(.*\)".*$/\1/; p;}' |
    sort -t. -k 1,1n -k 2,2n -k 3,3n -k 4,4n -k 5,5n |
    GREP_OPTIONS="" \grep "^${1:-}" | tail -n 1
}
```

Comment: I haven't noticed that 'curl' is a requirement for RVM. Thank you, I believe the local installation of 'curl' to the home folder (as @qqx suggested) is the easiest way to install RVM in my case.